# TextBox_TextChanged Event not firing in c#

Tags: c#

The DOB_TextChanged event not firing.My code is,

Aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB">
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="DOB" CssClass="datepick" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
               OnTextChanged="DOB_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

code behind,

```
protected void DOB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //mycode
}
```

am i did anything wrong??

Comment: And what is `//mycode`?

Comment: TextChanged event won't fire as you type in the textbox. It will fire when a postback happens on the page.

Comment: @P.Pat It doesn't matter what //mycode is, since the event isn't firing

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Since the Textbox's autopostback is set to true, he expected when user lost focus on the textbox, the page will automatically post back and the event will be fired

Comment: So you try to put break point in the event handler and when you tab out of the TextBox the breakpoint does not hit.

Comment: You probably don't have the Changed event registered with a +=

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  i tried it by putting break point but it does not hit. And i don't know where it is wrong

Comment: @user7415073 put a break point to `Page_load` and than check if anything goes wrong there or even it hit the breakpoint or not?

Comment: actually the above aspx code is inside the gridView.And it works, If i place that textBox outside the Gridview. then, what is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have to check one thing..**Go** to aspx  **(Design) page**. Select the button. and click F4(Properties). There you have to go **Event** area. Here, Check if the TextChanged event is given correctly, like in the server page.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple code

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
```

and

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("button_click event raised");
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Response.Write("text_changed event raised : "+ TextBox1.Text);
    }
```

Set the text box property AutoPostBack=True , and it will work when control goes out of TextBox only after change in text .If text is same than it will not raise the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinkButton` and `OnRowCommand` instead:

Aspx

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="test" CommandName="YourCommandName" runat="server">Test</asp:LinkButton>

</EditItemTemplate>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void Item_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "YourCommandName")
    {
         //to do
    }
}
```